# Pagination of a WP_Query Loop in a child-page page template

Tags: wp-query, pagination, page-template, child-pages

**See edit at bottom.**

I have a wp_query loop in a page template for a custom post type ("success_stories"). The loop itself works fine but I cannot seem to get pagination working. I've tried every solution I could find on these forums and everytime I try to navigate to /page/child-page/page/2/ WordPress sends me back to /page/child-page/ with a 301 redirect.

I have of course flushed the permalinks about 100 times. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<?php


if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

// Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => array( 'success_stories' ),
    'posts_per_page'        => '3',
    'paged'                 => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'practice_areas_taxonomy',
                'field'    => 'ID',
                'terms'    => array( 17 ),
            )
    )
);

// Instantiate custom query
$practice_area_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $practice_area_query;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $practice_area_query->have_posts() ) :

    echo '<div>';

    while ( $practice_area_query->have_posts() ) :
        $practice_area_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="<?php echo $pa_class_inner; ?>">

            <blockquote>&ldquo;<?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>&rdquo;</blockquote>


        </div>

    <?php endwhile;

    echo '</div>';

endif;


// Pagination
$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         
if ($total_pages > 1) {

    $big = 999999999;
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo '<nav class="pagination clearfix">';

    echo paginate_links(
        array(
            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => 'Prev',
            'next_text' => 'Next',
            'mid_size' => 1,
            'end_size' => 3
        )
    );

    echo '</nav>';   
}

wp_reset_postdata();

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
```

Where am I going wrong? Can this not be done from a (child?) page template?

Edit: adding the following rewrite rules almost resolves the issue:

```
// Primary Rewrite Rule
add_rewrite_rule( 'practice-areas/family-law/?', 'index.php?post_type=success_stories', 'top' );
// Pagination Rewrite Rule
add_rewrite_rule( 'practice-areas/family-law/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?post_type=success_stories&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

The only problem then is that (a) on paginated pages I'm suddenly in a different template (archive.php) and (b) WordPress seems to default to regular wp_query parameters. That is, it's "forgotten" all my args from the above query, as well as my offset, and I think even the taxonomy query.

Comment: Is there a reason this is a custom page template, and not just the post type archive?

Comment: This may not answer the question, but you should use `$total_pages = $practice_area_query->max_num_pages;` instead of having to do those `$temp_query` things.

Comment: if you don't have a second page on your page then it won't find anything and give a 404 or redirect to the first. Remember, WordPress operates on the main query and is unaware of your custom query, and the main query runs _before_ the page template is loaded ( how else would it know which page and which template to load ). If your template does not reference the page then is there a reason you didn't use a main archive template then the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the parameters of the query instead of creating a second query?

Comment: Also there's an extremely high chance the answer will involve custom rewrite rules, as well as overriding the multiple page pagination rules ( a pages content can contain sub-pages separated by a marker, all within the same `page`

Comment: The main reason is to get the url structure we need. For example, the parent page has various traditional child pages, then 2 child pages that include queries like this. 

If it's not possible to get pagination to work in this context, I'll next try to customize the  custom taxonomy archive structure, but that too would be a tricky, because the structure would be the opposite of your typical custom taxonomy structure:

example.com/stuff/term_name/taxonomy_name.  Normally term_name would come after taxonomy_name.

Comment: @JoshM, "everytime I try to navigate to `/page/child-page/page/2/`" - does the URL look like `example.com/success_stories/practice-areas/family-law/page/2/` or is it `example.com/practice-areas/family-law/page/2/` ? (note the `success_stories`) Can you clarify that in your question? Were you trying to make `/practice-areas/family-law/page/2/` works, or did you just want the `/success_stories/practice-areas/family-law/page/2/` to work without the 301 redirect?

Comment: (once again, note the `success_stories`) And actually, can you include your CPT's registration code?

Comment: @SallyCJ - it looks like example.com/practice-areas/family-law/success-stories/page/2/

"practice-areas" is the CPT slug. "Family-law" is the parent page slug. "Success-stories" is the child page slug.

PS I think I have a solution, will post later this morning.

Comment: You should have added that information to the post, but anyway, thanks for clarifying, and I hope my answer helps you more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that you managed to figure out a solution, which yes, does work. But you could make it more selectively, i.e. target just the specific pages, by using [`is_single( '<parent slug>/<child slug>' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/), e.g. `is_single( 'family-law/success-stories' )` in your case.

Secondly, it's not exactly the `redirect_canonical` *hook* which caused the (301) redirect on singular paginated post pages (with URL having the `/page/<number>`). Instead, it's [the `$addl_path` part](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L493) in the [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) *function* which fires the `redirect_canonical` hook. More specifically, that part runs only if `! is_single()` is true (and that the current page number is 2 or more), and thus:

- If the request (i.e. current page) URL was for a CPT at `example.com/practice-areas/family-law/success-stories/page/2/` where `practice-areas` is the CPT slug and `success-stories` is child of `family-law`, the redirect/canonical URL would **not** contain `page/2/` because `! is_single()` is false, hence `$addl_path` would be empty.

  The same scenario would also happen on `example.com/practice-areas/family-law/page/2/` (i.e. page 2 of the parent post) and other singular CPT pages, including regular posts (in the default `post` type), e.g. at `example.com/hello-world/page/2/`, *but not on singular Pages* (post type `page`) because `! is_single()` is false — because `is_single()` works with any post type, except `attachment` and `page`.
- So if the request URL does not match the canonical URL, then WordPress runs the (301) redirect, which explains why this happened: "*everytime I try to navigate to `/page/child-page/page/2/` WordPress sends me back to `/page/child-page/` with a 301 redirect*".

Also, `redirect_canonical()` is hooked on `template_redirect`, so instead of having the function runs the various logic of determining the redirect/canonical URL and yet you eventually return an empty string, you might better off just disable the function like so:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect', 1 );
function my_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_paged() && is_single( 'family-law/success-stories' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }
}
```

And yes, no extra rewrite rules are needed because WordPress already generated them (which handle the `/page/<number>`) for your CPT. But I don't know for sure why WordPress does the above `! is_single()` check.

Last but not least, in my original answer and comment as well, I suggested you to remove the `$temp_query` parts, and your reply was: "*I'm gonna keep the $temp_query bit though, since it allows our pagination component to work without the need to rewrite or complicate things*" and "*I think you were just saying it's not needed*".

So yes, you're right with that second sentence. But more precisely, I actually tested your template code where I put it in `single-practice-areas.php` and then removed the `$temp_query` parts (and used `$total_pages = $practice_area_query->max_num_pages;`), and the `/page/<number>` pagination worked just fine for me with the help of the above `my_template_redirect()` function.

So I wondered what exactly does the `$temp_query` fix, or why must you assign the `$wp_query` to `$practice_area_query`?

But if you really must keep it, then you need to move the `wp_reset_postdata();` to after the `$wp_query = $temp_query;`, i.e. after you restore the global `$wp_query` variable back to the actual main query. Because otherwise, if for example you run `the_title()`, you would see the title of the last post in your custom query and not the current (and the only) one in the main query.

Comment: I like your conditional a lot better. I'll try this later today to confirm it works. Thanks.

Comment: This works well. I'll select is the correct answer. 

I'm gonna keep the $temp_query bit though, since it allows our pagination component to work without the need to rewrite or complicate things.

Unless I'm missing something and you're saying there's an actual disadvantage to that? But I think you were just saying it's not needed.

Comment: Please check the last four paragraphs in my answer (I also reworded some other paragraphs).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the redirect_canonical filter. That was causing the 301 back to the child page itself.

The solution is to selectively disable that filter. Below is what I've done, though it's not quite as selective as I'd like.

But it does allow pagination to work, **without the need of any rewrite rules.**

```
// redirect_canonical is preventing pagination on PA child pages. This removes the filter in that context
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'namespace_prevent_redirect_on_pagination', 10 );
function namespace_prevent_redirect_on_pagination( $redirect_url ) {
    if ( is_singular('practice-areas') && !is_admin() && get_post()->post_parent ) {
        return '';
    }
 
    return $redirect_url;
}
```